# How to achieve a multi-column layout for footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, multicol, rotating

How can you achieve a multi-column layout for footnotes?

I have one page filled only with a rotated table (landscape layout, the `sidewaystable` environment). The table is annotated by a lot of footnotes which makes the page wider than I want. Since the texts of individual footnotes are quite small I have thought about laying them in two columns to lower the page width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can improve it with minipages. After the sidewaystable you have to increase the footnote counter, if another footnote appears.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\rule{\linewidth}{5cm}\par
The package sets the\footnotemark[1] footnotes\footnotemark[2] of a single-column document in two columns; 
the package offers a range of parameters to determine\footnotemark[3] the exact appearance\footnotemark[4] of the two columns.


\vspace{1cm}
\footnoterule\footnotesize
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
\textsuperscript{1} This is the first footnote. And here comes some nonsense text
                    to show that the linebreaks works \par
\textsuperscript{2} This is the second footnote.\par
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
\textsuperscript{3} This is the third footnote. \par
\textsuperscript{4} This is the fourth footnote.\par
\textsuperscript{5} This is the fourth footnote.\par
\textsuperscript{6} This is the fourth footnote.\par
\end{minipage}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! At first, it didn't work for me and I got a single column layout for the footnotes, but at second try, it worked (I have no clue why).

Answer (score 7):

Use [dblfnote](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=dblfnote) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dblfnote}
\begin{document}
The package sets the footnotes of a single-column document in two columns; the package offers a range of parameters to determine the exact appearance of the two columns.
\footnote{This is the first footnote.}
The package sets the footnotes of a single-column document in two columns; the package offers a range of parameters to determine the exact appearance of the two columns.
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
The package sets the footnotes of a single-column document in two columns; the package offers a range of parameters to determine the exact appearance of the two columns.
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the first footnote.}
The package sets the footnotes of a single-column document in two columns; the package offers a range of parameters to determine the exact appearance of the two columns.The package sets the footnotes of a single-column document in two columns; the package offers a range of parameters to determine the exact appearance of the two columns. \footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.} \footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.} 
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
\footnote{This is the third footnote.}
\footnote{This is the fourth footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: @user2716: didn't work in a sideways environment

Comment: Yes, it's a nice and easy method, but it unfortunately does not work for pages with landscape layout.

Comment: @user2716: It's good that you give a full compilable example; it would be even better if it was a bit shorter.

Comment: @Herbert and @jindrichm, please see my new response and sorry for answering very late. I am very new to this and did not notice your comments.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for my late response. I still can think of two other solutions that work in your situation and it is automatic. This is applied to Herbert's given example:

You can either use memoir class:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx}
\twocolumnfootnotes
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\rule{\linewidth}{5cm}\par
The package sets theof a single-column\footnote{This is a test.} document in two columns; 
the package offers a range of parameters\footnote{This is a test.} \footnote{This is a test.} to determinethe exact appearance of the two columns.\footnote{This is a test.}\footnote{This is a test.}\footnote{This is a test.}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

or you can use ledmac package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\foottwocolX{A}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\rule{\linewidth}{5cm}\par
The package sets theof a single-column\footnoteA{This is a test.} document in two columns; 
the package offers a range of parameters\footnoteA{This is a test.} \footnoteA{This is a test.} to determinethe exact appearance of the two columns.\footnoteA{This is a test.}\footnoteA{This is a test.}\footnoteA{This is a test.}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You specifically mentioned using a `sidewaystable`. In that case I would recomment to use [`threeparttable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable?lang=en), with which you can achieve the following:

[image: sidewaystable with threeparttable]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
        \centering
        \caption{Super informative caption}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
                Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 \\\hline
                Cell 1\tnote{*} & Cell 2\tnote{$\dagger$} & Cell 3\tnote{$\ddagger$} & Cell 4\tnote{\#}\\
                Cell 5\tnote{$\|$} & Cell 6\tnote{$\Delta$} & Cell 7\tnote{$\diamond$} & Cell 8\tnote{$\downarrow$}\\
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \footnotesize
                \item[*] Always
                \item[$\dagger$] look
                \item[$\ddagger$] on
                \item[\#] the
                \item[$\|$] bright
                \item[$\Delta$] side
                \item[$\diamond$] of
                \item[$\downarrow$] life!
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Note the [`para`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/threeparttable.pdf) option in the `\usepackage` statement, which causes the following behavior:

> **para** Notes come one-after-another without line breaks

To control the spacing between the table notes take at look at [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118743/threeparttable-notes-layout)