# How to show footnotes in multiple columns

Tags: footnotes

I am attaching an image of the footnote page, It uses up lot of vertical space. I want to appear this at the bottom either in itemized format or two / three columns format.
Two to three columns would be ideal because of better readability.

Thanks for your help
[image: footnote]

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8174/how-to-achieve-a-multi-column-layout-for-footnotes help?

Comment: Would typesetting the footnotes in a single paragraph be an option for you?

Comment: the solutions given in the above post did not work for me. I have footnotes at many places in the document and when I put entire document in sideways environment it started giving error on the line where my tables start. Once I took the sideways environment out my document worked fine. `dblfnote` works fine but gave two columns. I wish there is away to change number of columns on `dblfnote`

Comment: @Thorsten - yes that can be an option.

Comment: Hi. Can you give some more details about your engine? What package do you use to typeset hindi (if I'm not mistaken about the language...).
you might also check on [`bidi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bidi).

Comment: @Zakeri - `\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}` I am using `xelatex` yes this is Hindi

Comment: "when I put entire document in sideways environment"
 Would `\documentclass[landscape]{...}` or `\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}` or [landscape](http://ctan.org/pkg/landscape) package or `pdflandscape` (currently unable to find a reference for this) be alternatives for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If paragraph footnotes are fine, you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{bigfoot}
% \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}

% Or:
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}%

\newcommand{\parafn}{Text.\footnote{Footnote text}} %

\begin{document}

\parafn

\parafn

\parafn

\end{document}
```

The `memoir` class also has very customizable footnotes, including a `\paragraphfootnotes` command.

Comment: `\newcommand{\parafn}{Text.\footnote{Footnote text}} %` I am getting error here. That does not appear to be valid syntax for newcommand.

Comment: The command is fine as is; please describe the error you are seeing.  (And did you run the example file I gave you, or are you putting it into a different file?)

Comment: your example worked great, I just change the `newcommand` to this `\newcommand{\fnote}[1]{\footnote{#1}}` and wherever I want to use I just type `\fnote{desired footnote text}`

Comment: @Aku -- Great.  (And of course you could still use `\footnote` if you wanted --- depends on how good you editor handles syntax highlighting.   I usually only make up new names when I have more than one layer of footnotes.  Here I was just doing it to simplify the creation of the example document)