# How to create two column footnotes when using parallel package?

Tags: footnotes, parallel

I am using `parallel` package for two column parallel texts. By default the footnotes are all formatted in one column. Is there any way to generate two column footnotes under `parallel` environment? I am not asking to separate left and right column footnotes, just feel single column too space-wasting.

I've tried some packages like whatever in [How to achieve a multi-column layout for footnotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8174/how-to-achieve-a-multi-column-layout-for-footnotes).
But they don't seem to work with `parallel`.
Here is my pseudo code (using `dblfnote` package)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Verbose]{parallel}
\usepackage{dblfnote}

\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}{0.45\textwidth}{0.45\textwidth}

\ParallelLText{
    Aperture Science \footnote{where GLaDOS lives}
}

\ParallelRText{
    We do what we must, because we can
    \footnote{test subject}
    \footnote{test subject}
    \footnote{test subject}
    \footnote{test subject}
    ...
}

\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

Any thoughts or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: ...make combustible lemonade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ledmac` and `ledpar` might be overkill for your needs, but you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ledmac, ledpar, lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\foottwocolX{A}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{pairs}

  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering\pstart
    % \firstlinenum{100}\linenumincrement{100}% <-- to 'hide' line numbers
    \lipsum[1] Aperture
    Science%
    \footnote{where GLaDOS lives} 
    \pend\endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering\pstart
    % \firstlinenum{100}\linenumincrement{100}% <-- to 'hide' line numbers
    \lipsum[2]
    We do what we must, because we can %
    \footnote{test subject} %
    \footnote{test subject} %
    \footnote{test subject} %
    \footnote{test subject} 
    \pend\endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}

\Columns
\end{pairs}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note also that you could create some commands to simplify the expectations `ledmac` and `ledpar` have regarding the starting and stopping of paragraphs and parallel columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jon. Your answer really helps. One more thing, is it possible to parallel edit without line counting? Line numbers can be hidden, but there's still an unpleasant indent that shifts the margin of text block.

Comment: Wpipsi -- can you explain what you mean more clearly.  I changed the example to show where the text is flush to the textblock, and I don't see any difference between normal text and the text in between the `\begin{pairs} ... \end{pairs}`.