# threeparttable notes layout

Tags: notes, threeparttable

I am using threeparttable for adding notes to my table. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\par
Lets test the threeparttable package.
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Some very informative caption}
\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \toprule
    \textbf{1st Column} & \textbf{2nd Colimn} & \textbf{3rd Colimn} & \textbf{4th Colimn} \\ \midrule
      QWERTY\tnote{1}   &                     &                     &  \\
      ASDFGH\tnote{2}   &                     &                     &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] qwerty; \item[2] asdfgh
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\label{table:simDisimCoefNewDef}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produce the following:

[image: threeparttable]

So what I need is to set minimum distance between notes on same line like in normal text. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

The `para` setting in `threeparttable` uses an interesting collection of penalties and glue but I think you just want to change the length indicated (the default is `1em` I changed it to `6em` here) Unrelated but I also changed `[h]` to `[htp]` as using `h` on its own is asking the float to go to the end of the document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}

\makeatletter
\def\TPT@doparanotes{\par
   \prevdepth\z@ \TPT@hsize
   \TPTnoteSettings
   \parindent\z@ \pretolerance 8
   \linepenalty 200
   \renewcommand\item[1][]{\relax\ifhmode \begingroup
       \unskip
       \advance\hsize 10em % \hsize is scratch register, based on real hsize
       \penalty -45 \hskip\z@\@plus\hsize \penalty-19
       \hskip .15\hsize \penalty 9999 \hskip-.15\hsize
       \hskip .01\hsize\@plus-\hsize\@minus.01\hsize 
       \hskip 6em\@plus .3em
              %%%%%
      \endgroup\fi
      \tnote{##1}\,\ignorespaces}%
   \let\TPToverlap\relax
   \def\endtablenotes{\par}%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\par
Lets test the threeparttable package.
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Some very informative caption}
\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \toprule
    \textbf{1st Column} & \textbf{2nd Colimn} & \textbf{3rd Colimn} & \textbf{4th Colimn} \\ \midrule
      QWERTY\tnote{1}   &                     &                     &  \\
      ASDFGH\tnote{2}   &                     &                     &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] qwerty; \item[2] asdfgh
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\label{table:simDisimCoefNewDef}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess the question is how to *remove* the additional space and use a normal interword space (instead of 6em use 0em, of course). I'd notice also that `\centering` is to be used instead of `center` and that the `\label` should be nearer to the caption (just in case some `\refstepcounter` comes along).

Comment: It works with David code and @egreg advice.

Comment: @David Carlisle, could you please explain your code because I noticed different output in some cases, e.g. when putting \textit in \item. What are all this penalties for?

Comment: @alchemist_bg it's not my code the definition is just copied from three part table I just changed `1em` to `6em` I'm not sure why Donald had quite such a complicated collection, but he knows what he's doing:-) basically the idea is to allow extra flexibility between the notes and to encourage line breaking there rather than inside the note if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a built-in command `\tabularnote` to compose notes after the tabular. This list of notes is composed with the tools of the package `enumitem`. It's possible to customize with all the keys provided by `enumitem`. For example, the tokens inserted between two notes (in `para` mode) may be set with the key `itemjoin`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{nicematrix,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Some very informative caption}
\centering
\NiceMatrixOptions{notes/para}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c}
    \toprule
    \RowStyle{\bfseries}
    1st Column & 2nd Column & 3rd Column & 4th Column \\ \midrule
    QWERTY\tabularnote{qwerty}  & & &  \\
    ASDFGH\tabularnote{asdefgh} & & &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{table:simDisimCoefNewDef}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Some very informative caption}
\centering
\NiceMatrixOptions{notes/para,notes/enumitem-keys-para={itemjoin = ;\;}}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c}
    \toprule
    \RowStyle{\bfseries}
    1st Column & 2nd Column & 3rd Column & 4th Column \\ \midrule
    QWERTY\tabularnote{qwerty}  & & &  \\
    ASDFGH\tabularnote{asdefgh} & & &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{table:simDisimCoefNewDef}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]