# Why footnote is not displayed in the text?

Tags: footnotes

I have the following table in a text where the index of the footnote is displaced but not the note in the end of the page:

[image]

Code block:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Configuration of SANDIA research VAWTs} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
& Sandia 5-m & Simulation & Sandia 17-m & Simulation\\ [0.5ex]  
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
Rotor Diameter[m] & 5  &  5  & 17 & 17 \\ % inserting body of the table
Rotor Height[m] & ~7.3 & 7.3 & 25.1  & 25.1  \\
Number of Blades & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2 \\
Blade Length[m] & N/A  & FIND & 30.92 & FIND  \\
Swept area[m$^2$] & N/A & FIND & 284 & FIND \\
Airfoil & NACA 0012 & NACA 0012 & NACA 0015 & NACA 0015 \\
Chord[m] & 0.19/0.1 \footnotemark\footnotetext{the curved part of each blade is a NACA 0012 with a 19-cm chord while each straight section is simply steel of chord of   10-cm.In 1980 the blades where replaced with NACA 0015 airfoil\cite{sandia17}\cite{sandia5m}.} & 0.19 & 0.616/0.610 & 0.615 \\[1ex]
 % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin} 
\end{table}
```

I also used the following but with not desired results:

```
\footnote{}\footnotetext{blablabla}
```

or this one

```
 \footnote{blablabla}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post ***complete*** code i.e. a small, compilable document rather than a mere fragment. Put the footnote text outside the table - only the mark in the table.

Comment: Search the site for the topic [footnote] and [table]. Use the package `threeparttable`. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118743/threeparttable-notes-layout).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `threeparttable` package and its eponymous environment to typeset this table and its associated footnote. I further suggest you use the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package to get well-spaced horizontal lines without the need to engage in any visual formatting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\caption{Configuration of SANDIA research VAWTs}  \label{table:nonlin} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l c c c c@{}} % centered columns (4 columns)
\toprule
& Sandia 5-m & Simulation & Sandia 17-m & Simulation\\  
\midrule
Rotor Diameter[m] & 5  &  5  & 17 & 17 \\ % inserting body of the table
Rotor Height[m] & ~7.3 & 7.3 & 25.1  & 25.1  \\
Number of Blades & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2 \\
Blade Length[m] & N/A  & FIND & 30.92 & FIND  \\
Swept area[m$^2$] & N/A & FIND & 284 & FIND \\
Airfoil & NACA 0012 & NACA 0012 & NACA 0015 & NACA 0015 \\
Chord[m] & 0.19/0.1\tnote{1} & 0.19 & 0.616/0.610 & 0.615\\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] The curved part of each blade is a NACA 0012 with a 19-cm chord while each straight section is simply steel of chord of   10-cm.In 1980 the blades where replaced with NACA 0015 airfoil \cite{sandia17,sandia5m}.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `\footnotetext` command outside the `table` environment. Eg:

```
\begin{document}
... 
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
 entry1 & entry2 & entry3 & entry4\footnotemark & entry5\\
 ...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\footnotetext{This should show up fine now}
```