# Let \tablenotes in threeparttable appear as justified text block

Tags: threeparttable, tablenotes

I'm using the `para` option to typeset table notes as a single justified text block, which often works, but not always. The attached code produces this:
[image]
There is a break between "b" and "c". It seems that `threeparttable` checks whether it can save a line by putting it all into one block, and if not it doesn't. But that can yield some ugly line-breaks, which make my document appear inconsistently formatted. How can I instruct it to *always* append *all* entries without breaking the line, so that the result looks like this:
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\linewidth}
\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{table}[!tbh]
\begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{cll}
            \toprule some&table&content\\\midrule
            1&2&3\\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item  aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aa a aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa a a a aa 
        \item  bbb bbbb b bbbbbbbbb b bb bbbbbb b bbbb b bbbbbbbbb b bb bbbbbbbbb bbbb b bbbbbbbbb b bb bbbbbb b bbbb b bbbbbbbbb b bb bbbbbb
        \item ccc ccc c c cccccc c c cccccc c c cccccc c c cccccc c c cccccc c c ccc c c cc
    \end{tablenotes}%
\end{threeparttable}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** I edited the code, removing a few "c"s from it, the original code did not fit the screenshot.

**EDIT2:** There's a related issue here: [threeparttable notes layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118743/threeparttable-notes-layout), and the solution might help answering my question. I just can't seem to find out how.

Comment: it works as expected if you remove `\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\linewidth}`.  main features of `threeparttable` is that notes is below table and that they are not wide then table (as i understand it).

Comment: No, when I remove this line it works only in this particular example, it doesn't actually solve the problem that the `tablenotes` environment likes adding line-breaks before `\item`s. In my actual document tables are as wide as the text, thus the problem then remains the very same. Only, for the MWE I used a smaller table.

Comment: i cant reproduce correct work of threeparttable anymore. so you have right.